# How to use foreach/while to loop only through each 10000000?

Tags: php

That the loop dosen't loop through 10000000, 10000001. But just 10000000 then 20000000. Is it possible? Language PHP.

Comment: It sounds like you'd be best using a for loop.

Comment: what is the code you have written to achieve this ?

Comment: No, it's not possible to do that in PHP

Comment: Wait wut, it doesn't loop through 10000000 but just 10000000? I don't get it.

Comment: *facepalm* Its help with the CODE im asking for... I have not written any code yet with this. OMG!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what language you are using.  For example in PHP you could do this.

```
<?php

$stride = 10000000;
$num_iterations = 10;

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_iterations * $stride; $i += $stride) {
  // Do stuff with $i
}
```

However, as usual when programming, things can be done different ways.  Often a different way leads to simpler code.  For example, you might be able to get away with this:

```
<?php

$stride = 10000000;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $num = $i * $stride;
  // Do stuff with $num
}
```